# Convert Android.Graphics.Bitmap to Image

Tags: android, bitmap, xamarin

I am trying to get screenshot of the view as follows. I am getting Bitmap and I need to convert it to to Image to add into PDF generator.

```
using (var screenshot = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(200, 100,Bitmap.Config.Argb8888))
{
    var canvas = new Canvas(screenshot);
    rootView.Draw(canvas);

    using (var screenshotOutputStream = new FileStream(screenshotPath,System.IO.FileMode.Create))
    {
        screenshot.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 90, screenshotOutputStream);
        screenshotOutputStream.Flush();
        screenshotOutputStream.Close();
    }
}
```

My question is how to convert `Android.Graphics.Bitmap -->screenshot` to `Image` ?

I want to replace the url with Image itself which comes from BitMap.

```
String imageUrl = "myURL";
Image image = Image.GetInstance (new Uri (imageUrl));
document.Add(image);
```

Comment: System.Drawing.Image is not supported in Xamarin Android.

Comment: Please see my three lines of code - just added to my question- which is working in `Xamarin.Android`. Do you have any recommendation of getting screenshot of the view and assign it to the Image to generate pdf.

Comment: That's an Android.Media.Image.  Sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
public Bitmap getScreenshotBmp() {


    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

    File path = Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    File file = new File(path, uniqueID + ".jpg");
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    screenshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, fileOutputStream);

    try {
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return screenshot;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Udi, it seems to me that it is still `Bitmap`? I have not seen `Image` conversion in the code? Am I missing something?

Comment: This line suppose to do that:
screenshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, fileOutputStream);

Comment: Where does `screenshot` come from?

Comment: screenshot type?

Comment: Question has "xamarin" tag, why is this Java?!