# How to create custom URL based xaml namespace (xmlns) in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, forms, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to create a custom url based namespace in xamarin forms so that i can use `xmlns:lib="http://schemas.officename.com/component/2015/xaml"` instead of clr namespace like  `xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:Forms.Library.ontrols;assembly=Forms.Library"`

like the examples here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and

http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2013/05/how-to-create-custom-xmlns-namespaces.html

i tried importing

**`using System.Windows.Markup;`**

in AssemblyInfo.cs, but it is not found also **XmlnsDefinition** and **XmlnsPrefix** are not there.

do i need to import any specific dll or those are not implemented in Xamarin Forms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this approach is (currently) supported in the Xamarin.Forms implementation of XAML.

Comment: Hi Jason, do you have any idea for the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114020/convert-android-graphics-bitmap-to-image